# Django template tags - arrange result of queryset

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to format my results in a table.

```
<tr>
   <td>A6</td>
   <td>A6 title</td>
   <td>
       {% for record in a6titles %}
          titles: {{ record }}
       {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>
```

The data displays in a single row. I would like each result item to be displayed in its own row. I am sure this is very simple; however, I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# You need to put your tr tag in for loop

{% for record in a6titles %}
<tr>
    <td>A6</td>
    <td>A6 title</td>
    <td>titles: {{ record }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```